# Can I use a C header containing designated initializers as C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to interface to a C file, in a C++ environment, and part of it defines a data structure once on declaration, and assigns each member with designated initializers:

```
59    struct {
60       int x;
61       int y;
62       int z;
63    }point_singleton = {
64       .x = 0,
65       .y = 0,
66       .z = 0,
67    };
```

However if I try to interface to it in visual studio in a C++ environment for other testing purposes, I get syntax errors:

> (64): error C2059: syntax error: '.'
>
> (67): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
>
> (67): error C2059: syntax error: '}'

Is it possible to work around it without changing the code?

Comment: Wait, so your want to workaround without changing the code in question? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: C++ and C have different syntax - so it is not possible without changing the code

Comment: Even if the this portion of the code is defined in .c file? while the code trying to interface in a .cpp?.

Comment: If the file has `.c` as suffix, VS should compile it automatically with the C compiler. Does it not?

Comment: C++ as a (mostly, but in some cases sometimes not) superset of C is somewhat locked to a (ahem) vintage C.  Both C and C++ have continued to evolve, but they've diverged -- since the C community doesn't feel obligated to be constrained by C++ nor try to make C to be C++ compatible.  And I think rightly so, even though I'm on the C++ side of the fence.

Comment: @Eljay: C++ is **not** a superset of C! One should never even try to invoke the impression. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics! And it is not only the C "community" which does not try, but more the C++ standardisation working group. Btw. C and C++ are not specified by communities, but ISO working groups. That's a completely different process.

Comment: On a sidenote: defining variables in a header is strongly deprecated in both languages and never a good idea.

Comment: @Olaf • sorry, that's why I pointed out it as "mostly".  I agree with your comment that even invoking the impression is a disservice.

Comment: Continuing the train of thought brought up by Olaf (which I concur):  compiling C code with a C++ compiler is not a good idea.  Trying to have source code straddle both C and C++ is going to end in tears.

Comment: @Olaf you're right, never mentioned it's defined in a header, it's actually defined in a c source file, and I'm trying to bypass it by including .c file. In the past I'd stub it out by defining a function on the bottom protected by preprocessor definition to just return address of instantiated structure.

Comment: @Iancovici: Interesting if you feel the truth is concdescending. It was just a well-meant hint, as from your profile you seem to intend to work in that field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because that syntax is not legal in C++.

Compile your C code as C, as C is not a subset of C++.